# Style UL LI list so all elemetns are vertically aligned and flushed left?

Tags: css, navigation

I'm building a footer navigation with four columns:

```
<ul>
    <li>Top Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>sub 1a</li>
            <li>sub 1b</li>
            <li>sub 1c</li>
            <li>sub 1d</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Top Level 2
        <ul>
            <li>sub 2a</li>
            <li>sub 2b</li>
            <li>sub 2c</li>
            <li>sub 2d</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    .... (repreat 2 more times)....
</ul>
```

I'm having trouble getting the top level item and the sub items left aligned so they are all flush and aligned left. I've got them into 4 columns ok, but they look like this:

```
Top Level 1        Top Level 2
    sub 1a            sub 2a
    sub 1b            sub 2b
    sub 1c            sub 2c
    sub 1d            sub 2d
```

If needs be, I can post the CSS that I have now.

Comment: you might have the default padding-left on that sub `<ul>` pushing your sub items a bit to the right, therefore creating that gap

Comment: add `ul { padding: 0; }`. You are seeing the default `<ul>` styling probably

Comment: you need to reset `padding-left` to 0

Comment: yep `ul{padding-left: 0px;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex for do that, well you can use float as well, but I like use flex, very easy. For add a new column you don´t need to do anything.

Here you have a full example to play:
http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/waqxmY

the important things are:
1- apply a different style to the first ul and li to the others for that I add a class in the first ul. After I can use a child selector ´>´

2.- Flex require in this case add an element with display: flex. The internal element can be allocated in differents ways, we don't use any special here. This element is the first ul as well.

3.- the magic is, in the first li elements I add the property flex. This property in this context permits auto calc the width in this elements. If you put '1' this mind a single unit, if you put '2' this mind double...

```
ul.wrapper{
  display:flex;
}

ul.wrapper>li{
   flex:1;
}
```

4. add the prefixed (browser compatibility) and a few decoration.

Answer (score 1):

try resetting padding-left

```css
ul, li{list-style:none; padding-left:0}
div{-webkit-column-count: 2;column-count: 2;}
```

```html
<div>

    <li>Top Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>sub 1a</li>
            <li>sub 1b</li>
            <li>sub 1c</li>
            <li>sub 1d</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Top Level 2
        <ul>
            <li>sub 2a</li>
            <li>sub 2b</li>
            <li>sub 2c</li>
            <li>sub 2d</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

   
</div>
```